# Embed a generated Excel chart in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The appearance of the ordinary charts widget of MS Access 2010 is not very attractive.

Is it possible (and how?) to embed the rather attractive Excel charts in Access and fill them with data from a query (dynamically)?

PS:

Because I want to update the chart depending on user input the use of pivot-charts is not possible.

Comment: You can link an unbound control to an Excel file, but you may find that where you had one problem, you now have half a dozen.

Comment: BTW Exactly how much user input? Are you talking about limiting the data or a completely different table?

Comment: @Remou The user can edit the filter parameters on the query (select boxes, text fields, date, etc...). So the user can limit the data of the same table.

Comment: @Remou I tried that and the problem is that if I change the query by the `RecordSource`-property of the form the chart does not display any data anymore.

Comment: I have added a few notes.

Comment: I found an MS article for that problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298046/en-us?fr=1

Comment: That is for 2002, 2010 is quite different. I strongly recommend you use a query as the record source, as illustrated below. It will give you a lot more control. Note also that you can have quite complicated where statements with DoCmd.OpenForm and these statements will be applied to the pivot chary form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on using a chart

```
Sub OpenMyChart()
''You could do this part without code, but let use say you want VBA
sSQL = "SELECT Table1.AText AS ACategory, Table1.ANumber AS AData, " _
     & "Table1.ADate AS AFilter, Table1.ATime AS ASeries " _
     & "FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ADate=#1/20/2012#"

''This is the query that my Chart form uses
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chart").SQL = sSQL

''You can use a Where statement for opening the form, too
DoCmd.OpenForm "Chart", acFormPivotChart, , "ACategory='Bob'"
End Sub
```

Two other approaches using a similar set up with a subform.

/1. Use link child and master fields

The link master fields are set to the names of the listbox controls and the link child fields are set to the relevant fields for the chart:

```
Link Master Field: List1;List2
Link Child Field: AFilter;ACategory
```

Clicking the relevant control redraws the chart.

[image: chart]

/2. Use a query and force a redraw:

```
Private Sub List1_Click()
sSQL = "SELECT Table1.AText AS ACategory, Table1.ANumber AS AData, " _
     & "Table1.ADate AS AFilter, Table1.ATime AS ASeries " _
     & "FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ADate=#" _
     & Format(Me.List1, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"1/13/2013#"

''This is the query that my Chart form uses
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chart").SQL = sSQL

''Chart is the name of the subform control, and confusingly, 
''the name of the embedded form.
Me.Chart.SourceObject = "Chart"
End Sub
```

Comment: This will work. But  unfortunately it does not fit in the program I have to change. There are several tabs on the left side and some filter inputs on the right side. The intended use is to 'live refresh' the selected tab (some statistics, detail view, etc) with the filters set. This works well in all cases but in pivot charts.

Comment: It is tested with a pivot chart.

Comment: The pivotchart refreshes but it does destroy all fieldsets. After setting the `RecordSource` and calling `Requery` I have to set the field set programatically (see this [Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/programming-pivottable-pivotchart-views-in-access-HA001034579.aspx))